# Execute a Method within WPF Application using .Net Standard Project

Tags: wpf

My **.Net standard project** is calling a method within a **WPF application** using `reflection`.

Method Calling Code in my .NET standard Project...

```
            string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Google.Cast.DesktopV2.exe");
            var asm = Assembly.LoadFile(path);
            Type t = asm.GetType("Google.Cast.DesktopV2.Utility.PlayMedia");
            MethodInfo methodInfo = t.GetMethod("FindMediaPlayer");

            var o = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
           methodInfo.Invoke(o);
```

and here is my Method within **WPF Application**.

```
    public MediaElement FindMediaPlayer()
    {
        return ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).VideoPlayer;
    }
```

**VideoPlayer** is a ***MediaElement*** within my XAML file. I am getting the error "***The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'***" , is there anyway I can achieve this using reflection?

Comment: MediaElement is a DependencyObject, which means you can only reference it on the same thread it was created on. Exception applies for a DependencyObject that implements Freezable (which is not the case here). A frozen instance can be passed across thread boundaries. Make sure the instance is created on the UI thread.

Comment: it is created on UI thread, however I am having hardtime accessing it using a method (which is called by another .net app)

Comment: As I said before: _"you can only reference it on the same thread it was created on"_. Also the error message is pretty clear.